# Progress bar width

Tags: jquery, css, width, var

My code is designed to set the width of my progress bar by calculating the percentage and passing it as a style.width. I am a novice, so apologise for the bad code:

JQuery

```
$(document).ready(function() {
var width=(1/5*100);
$('#progress_bar').css('width','=width + "%"');
});
```

HTML

```
<div id="progress_bar" style="height:1em; background:red; display:block;"></div>
```

Could someone with a second to spare please help me to get it working and show me where I've gone wrong so I can learn from this?

http://jsfiddle.net/SyxAM/

Comment: Why do want to calculate in jQuery? You can directly use css like this: 
    #progress_bar{
        width: 20%
    }

Comment: @HarshithJ.V. The progress bar is animated as the page trashes a series of assets. As it progresses, the progress increases as the var width changes ie. (1/5*100), (1/4*100), (1/3*100), etc.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

The string `'=width + "%"'` can't be the value of a css parameter.

You probably wanted

```
 $('#progress_bar').css('width', width + "%");
```

Comment: Thanks, that's fixed it, I see the punctuation was stopping the var and treating it as a value. Thank you :)

Answer (score 1):

this will solve your problem

```
var width=(1/5*100);

$('#progress_bar').css('width',width + "%");
```

​

Answer (score 1):

Your variable appending was wrong.It should be like this;

```
$(document).ready(function() {
var width=(1/5*100);
$('#progress_bar').css('width', width + "%");
});
```

You can see here http://jsfiddle.net/SyxAM/2/