# Using JavaScript to alter attributes in a MVC web application

Tags: javascript, html, asp.net-mvc

I am trying to increase the progress of the progress bar by a fixed parameter irrespective of the current value. However, I am not able to extract the current value using the .value function. So, any help is great.

Also, is it okay to include this in my view itself or should I use a controller for the same?

```html
@{
    ViewBag.Title = "Test";
}

<h2>@ViewBag.Title.</h2>
<h3>@ViewBag.Message</h3>

<p>Testing Page</p>


<div class="progress progress-striped active progress-sm">
    <div class="progress-bar progress-bar-success" name="blah" role="progressbar" aria-valuenow="45" aria-valuemin="0" aria-valuemax="100" style="width: 45%" id="pb1">
        <span class="sr-only">45% Complete</span>
    </div>
</div>

<input type="button" value="Change Width" onclick="increase()" class="btn btn-default btn-sm" />


<script type="text/javascript">
    function increase() {
        var pwidth = document.getElementById("pb1").style.width.value;
        pwidth=pwidth+10;
        var str = pwidth + "%";
        document.getElementById("pb1").style.width = str;
    }
</script>
```

Comment: Try this process bar : http://jsfiddle.net/SyxAM/2/    Second One is : https://stackoverflow.com/questions/11947220/progress-bar-width

Comment: Hi Yash,
This is a duplicate question. You asked same query yesterday and even marked a response as an answer. If your query was not resolved then please make amendments in the same question.

Comment: Hey Rudraksh, yesterday I asked to change it to a fixed value while this is incremental. I edited the question but I was asked to make a new one so I made one.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You just need to use `parseInt`:

```
<script type="text/javascript">
    function increase() {
        var pwidth = parseInt(document.getElementById("pb1").style.width);
        console.log(pwidth);  // output to console
        pwidth += 10;
        var str = pwidth + "%";
        document.getElementById("pb1").style.width = str;
    }
</script>
```

Note: In future you can just use `console.log(pwidth);` for debugging - will show value on console in the F12 Dev tools console. In the original case it was showing as `undefined`.

Comment: Works perfectly, thanks and yep I just saw the values in the console. Thanks!

Also, since I am new to MVC, is it okay to alter it in this way in the view itself or should I be using a controller to do the same?

Comment: It depends what you are trying to accomplish? Are you are trying to increment the value based off some business logic in controller, then you can pass the value. But if you just want to keep track on client side with javascript that's fine too.